# wp-includes/SimplePie/ is used for what?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I have not installed SamplePie but I have this `/myhost/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie`
A php file in that cause fatal error.

The error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in
/home/myhost/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/IRI.php on line 432
```

Code at line 432:

```
elseif (strpos($input, '/../') === 0)           {
                $input = substr($input, 3);
                $output = substr_replace($output, '', strrpos($output, '/')); // error_line
}
```

There is no new memory allocation done here and I wonder how that error is created?

My question is What possibly may happen if I delete that folder?

Comment: I don't think this is a core folder - where is it being included from?

Comment: @halfer : Is I told I don't have samplepie plugin installed. But will my wordpress database functionality be effected if I delete this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you delete this folder the function of [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) will be gone and maybe causing a lot more errors. I believe it is for parsing feed data. (see: [WordPress Codex: fetch_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) - for example).

Here a few things you can try:

1. Contact your Hosting Provider to get more memory. (see: [Description of core php.ini directives - Resource Limits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php))
2. Try to set up your limit yourself. Maybe you limit your memory yourself at the wordpress config file. (wp-config.php -> `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`) (see: [WordPress Codex - Increasing memory allocated to PHP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php))
3. Try to deactivate all plugins. Then, if the error is gone, activate one after one, to see where the error is caused (resp. which plugin).

Comment: I have defined the memory limit, But no use. I haven't installed sample pie. I was wondering hoe did that get there.? Is it inbuilt with some functions of wordpress?

Comment: Maybe it comes with your theme?

Comment: I think all theme files are located in public_html/wp-content/themes.  Should I add the error line so that you can find what the problem is..?

Comment: I found this about the use of SimplePie [WordPress Codex - fetch_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed). SimplePie is for parsing feed data in your WordPress installation. The best solution would be to do step 1 from my answer above.

Comment: I haven't installed samplepie plugin !!. so how will the step 1 work.?

Comment: I have enough memory In my host. But still the error I wonder!

Comment: If that folder is not with the WP database. Will that effect my database if I delete that folder.

Comment: Try to deactivate all plugins, I found a few solutions for this problem, where people had issues with some gallery plugins. I would try to avoid delete this file, if you don't know all dependencies of this functions.

Comment: I tried to deactivate all the plugins and found the error causing plugin.It worked. Thanks for the support. Update the answer and I will accept the answer. But what is wp-includes/SimplePie/ used for since it has nothing to do with the plugin samplepie but with all plugins.?

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer. Could you tell which plugin caused the error?